# Can't connect when charger is plugged in

Tags: 18.10

Since I upgraded to Cosmic 18.10 im experiencing a weird bug. Whenever I turn on my laptop with the AC adapter on, it boots just fine until its time to connect to a session, and then it loops : enter password, go to the usual purple screen and then go back to the connection menu, waiting for a password... If I unplug the adapter and type my password it connects just fine and I can then plug it back on with no issue...

Nothing ruining the experience, but still its a problem I'd like to address... Anyone has ever experienced a similar situation ?

Comment: It may be due to some problem with adapter, AC noise etc.

Comment: When you say "connect" do you mean log in?

Comment: @Amanda yes log in :)

Comment: @Vijay no i dont think so because it was just fine before the update, im sure it is software related